# I will give you the silent treatment

Tags: meaning, idioms

Sometimes, people tell you that they are not talking to you. For example, you have a spat with your girlfriend, and then she tells you she is not talking to you for three days.

Is it possible for someone to say this? Is it correct and natural sounding?

***If you forget to buy me a gift, I will give you the silent treatment for 3 days.***

Comment: A threat like that *never* sounds natural, especially from someone over the age of 5.

Comment: It possibly meant, 'she won't talk to him for three days.' Not sure whether it is natural or not.

Comment: this is a conditional sentence, expressing  non-past realis. it's fine.

Comment: It is _not_ fine. It does not sound natural.

Answer (score -1):

It does not sound natural and I cannot think of a way to make it sound natural.

Wife:  *You better not forget to get me an anniversary gift.*

Husband:  *What could possibly happen if I did?*

Wife:  *We'll see how you will like it when you have no one to speak to for three days.*

Husband:  *You mean the "silent treatment"?*

Wife:  *Exactly.*

Husband:  *I will look forward to it.*

Comment: Okay, I am not talking about rational or "adult" behavior. Sometimes adults can act in a very childish way. In that case, is something like that possible? And, could children say something like that?

Comment: If it is a child, then I would expect to hear something like this:  "I'm not talking to you!"